# Reduce fan speed of ATI GPU with radeon open source driver

Tags: radeon

I have a Radeon HD 6950 connected to two screens on a machine running archlinux.

Recently I changed from the proprietary to the open source driver due to dropped catalyst support. Unfortunately by default the fans are very noisy by default - apparently the power saving mechanisms do not work properly.

I set `/sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_method` to `profile`
and `/sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_profile` to `low`. This seems to work

```
# cat /sys/kernel/debug/dri/0/radeon_pm_info
default engine clock: 800000 kHz
current engine clock: 249990 kHz
default memory clock: 1250000 kHz
current memory clock: 1250000 kHz
voltage: 900 mV
PCIE lanes: 16
```

Unfortunately it does only help a little with the fan noise.
I also tried `dynpm` which doesn't really seem to have an effect (possibly due to the dual head setup).

Previously, with the catalyst drivers, I had issues with fan noise after suspend, but I was able to use the "ATI Overclocking Utility" to reduce both shader and memory frequency which muted the fans.

Also I have dual boot windows running and there is no issue with fan noise in idle on Windows.

Kernel Version:
`Linux desktux 3.10.7-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Aug 15 11:55:34 CEST 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Update:
I tried the mainline 3.11 kernel since it is supposed to [improve power management](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver#Kernel_3.11.x_.28Ubuntu_13.10.2BAC8-Saucy.29_and_Later). Unfortunately Xorg won't utilize radeon in that case but rather VESA. VESA is actually perfectly fine regarding the fan speed, but does not support dual monitor.

Update:
With Kernel 3.15, the radeon.dpm=1 option seems to work regarding the reduction of power consumption. I had to explicitly enable it though even though I thought it was used by default. However, even though the system uses less power than under windows (both idle), the **fans are still more noisy**. I also measured that the the dual monitor setup uses 50 W more power than a single monitor (idle, similar numbers for Windows/Linux/BIOS).

Comment: dynpm works with kernels >= 3.11 and it does not work with dual displays.